# How to to divide this list into the sets with four elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, sets

I have a list

```
list={{1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 8, 9}, {1, 6, 18, 19}, {1, 8, 32, 33}, {1, 12, 
  12, 17}, {1, 18, 30, 35}, {1, 22, 46, 51}, {1, 34, 38, 51}, {2, 3, 
  6, 7}, {2, 5, 14, 15}, {2, 6, 9, 11}, {2, 7, 26, 27}, {2, 9, 42, 
  43}, {2, 10, 11, 15}, {2, 10, 25, 27}, {2, 14, 23, 27}, {2, 14, 49, 
  51}, {2, 18, 39, 43}, {2, 19, 34, 39}, {2, 21, 42, 47}, {2, 26, 29, 
  39}, {2, 43, 46, 63}, {3, 4, 12, 13}, {3, 6, 22, 23}, {3, 8, 36, 
  37}, {3, 14, 18, 23}, {3, 16, 24, 29}, {3, 24, 28, 37}, {3, 30, 46, 
  55}, {4, 4, 7, 9}, {4, 5, 20, 21}, {4, 7, 32, 33}, {4, 8, 19, 
  21}, {4, 9, 48, 49}, {4, 12, 39, 41}, {4, 13, 16, 21}, {4, 17, 28, 
  33}, {4, 24, 33, 41}, {4, 28, 35, 45}, {4, 32, 47, 57}, {4, 33, 36, 
  49}, {5, 6, 30, 31}, {5, 8, 44, 45}, {6, 6, 7, 11}, {6, 6, 17, 
  19}, {6, 7, 42, 43}, {6, 10, 15, 19}, {6, 10, 33, 35}, {6, 13, 18, 
  23}, {6, 14, 27, 31}, {6, 17, 30, 35}, {6, 18, 43, 47}, {6, 21, 22, 
  31}, {6, 27, 38, 47}, {6, 35, 42, 55}, {6, 41, 42, 59}, {7, 14, 22, 
  27}, {7, 16, 28, 33}, {7, 30, 30, 43}, {7, 40, 40, 57}, {8, 8, 31, 
  33}, {8, 9, 12, 17}, {8, 11, 16, 21}, {8, 19, 40, 45}, {8, 20, 25, 
  33}, {8, 21, 48, 53}, {8, 24, 27, 37}, {8, 28, 49, 57}, {9, 12, 20, 
  25}, {9, 18, 38, 43}, {9, 24, 32, 41}, {9, 32, 36, 49}, {10, 10, 23,
   27}, {10, 10, 49, 51}, {10, 14, 35, 39}, {11, 12, 24, 29}, {11, 18,
   42, 47}, {11, 36, 48, 61}, {12, 15, 16, 25}, {12, 16, 21, 29}, {12,
   19, 48, 53}, {12, 21, 28, 37}, {12, 24, 31, 41}, {12, 24, 41, 
  49}, {12, 27, 44, 53}, {12, 31, 36, 49}, {12, 36, 37, 53}, {13, 14, 
  34, 39}, {13, 16, 40, 45}, {14, 14, 47, 51}, {14, 17, 46, 51}, {14, 
  18, 21, 31}, {14, 22, 29, 39}, {14, 31, 38, 51}, {14, 39, 42, 
  59}, {15, 18, 26, 35}, {15, 24, 40, 49}, {16, 20, 37, 45}, {16, 28, 
  47, 57}, {17, 20, 20, 33}, {17, 32, 44, 57}, {18, 21, 38, 47}, {18, 
  25, 30, 43}, {18, 26, 45, 55}, {18, 27, 34, 47}, {18, 42, 49, 
  67}, {19, 22, 26, 39}, {19, 30, 42, 55}, {20, 28, 29, 45}, {20, 36, 
  45, 61}, {20, 39, 48, 65}, {22, 31, 34, 51}, {22, 37, 46, 63}, {23, 
  24, 24, 41}, {23, 24, 36, 49}, {23, 28, 44, 57}, {24, 29, 48, 
  61}, {24, 36, 43, 61}, {25, 32, 40, 57}, {25, 36, 48, 65}, {26, 38, 
  43, 63}, {27, 28, 36, 53}, {28, 28, 41, 57}, {30, 30, 41, 59}, {30, 
  45, 46, 71}, {31, 42, 42, 67}, {33, 44, 48, 73}, {34, 37, 38, 
  63}, {35, 40, 44, 69}, {40, 45, 48, 77}}
```

Now I want to divide this list into the sets with four elements, e.g

```
{{{1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 8, 9}, {1, 6, 18, 19}, {1, 8, 32, 33}},{{1, 12, 12, 17}, {1, 18, 30, 35}, {1, 22, 46, 51}, {1, 34, 38, 51}},...}}}
```

I divide them by hand. How can I tell Mathematica to do this?

Comment: Take a look at `UpTo` as well from the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpTo.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Partition[list, 4]` will do it.